# Swiffy Conversion Error (Flash to HTML5)

Tags: html, canvas, google-swiffy

I've converted a Flash SWF file to HTML5 using Google Swiffy.

This works fine in Firefox.

However, in IE8, I'm receiving these errors:

'swiffy' is undefined

'stage' is null or not an object

In IE, if you visit the Google Swiffy gallery section (http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/gallery.html), and click on any of the examples, you'll receive similar errors (or, at least, I do). So maybe this is an existing issue.

I'll also contact Google to see if there's a solution to this issue.

Here's a snippet of the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Swiffy output</title>
<script src="http://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v3.5/runtime.js"></script>
<script>swiffyobject = {"tags":
[{"id":1,"height":194,"width":609,"data":"data:image/jpeg;
base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkS

...there's a lot of converted code, most of it looks like the gibberish above...

</script>
</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden;margin:0;">

<script>var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.body, swiffyobject);</script>
<script>stage.start();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I did begin converting the Flash file by coding it myself using Canvas. I'll probably continue with it. I was just pressed for time to get this done, and would like to have these errors resolved.

Thanks.

Stephen

(BTW, can I attach a file? The code is really lengthy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because HTML5 Canvas is not supported in IE8

You could use the [excanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) library but it is horrible with animation. excanvas uses VML to emulate canvas commands and pretend that it works on IE7/8

excanvas has not been updated since 2009 and I really recommend against supporting IE8 if you want to use Canvas. It's possible an SVG/VML solution would be better, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:
Download the swfobject.js and keep this file in folder "scripts".

Put this code in header section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
```

in swiffy file put this (bellow  swiffy script):

```
<script type="text/javascript">swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.mysite.com/flash_files/myflash.swf", "swiffycontainer", "638", "500", "8.0.0", "myflash.swf", {}, {menu:"false", scale:"noscale", wmode:"transparent"}, {} ); </script>
```

Comment: I completed this project last year and no longer have the files to work with. I would have loved to try this solution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The above (using swfobject.js) is a good solution! 
Basically use the swf in Flash supported env and HTML fallback in case of others.

Comment: you'll be able to comment on answers once you have gained enough rep :-)